[RN-Android]: react-native-keychain - Not able to retrieve credentials from App B after storing credentials from App A
Here's a breakdown of the issue:
Note - Facing issue with Android, iOS is working fine
Step 1: Storing credentials from App A:
I successfully stored credentials (e.g., username and password) using react-native-keychain within my React Native application (let's call it App A).
Step 2: Attempting to retrieve credentials from App B:
After storing the credentials in App A, I am are trying to retrieve them from another application, let's call it App B. However, I'm encountering difficulties in retrieving the credentials using react-native-keychain.
Reference code -
  const storeData = async () => {
    const result = await Keychain.setGenericPassword(
      'credentials',
      'test_user@demo.com|test123',
      {
        service: 'com.demo.cred',
      },
    );
    console.log(' ~ storeCredentials ~ result:', result);
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    const credentials = await Keychain.getGenericPassword({
      service: 'com.demo.cred',
    });
    console.log(' ~ retrieveCredentials ~ credentials:', credentials);
  };

  const resetData = async () => {
    const result = await Keychain.resetGenericPassword({
      service: 'com.demo.cred',
    });
    console.log(' ~ resetCredentials ~ result:', result);
  };

Note: I am able to retrieve credentials from App A after storing from App A but not able to retrieve credentials from App B. Though this flow works fine for iOS.
Setup issue -
According to the docs for linking manually https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keychain#option-manually-1, I am facing issue for the below step.

Edit your MainApplication.java (deep in android/app/src/main/java/...) to look like this (note two places to edit):

package com.myapp;

+ import com.oblador.keychain.KeychainPackage;

....

public class MainActivity extends extends ReactActivity {

  @Override
  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
              new MainReactPackage(),
+             new KeychainPackage()
      );
  }
  ...
}


This is my MainApplication.java

....
import com.oblador.keychain.KeychainPackage; // --> added import here

....

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication, DefaultLifecycleObserver {
    static Context activityContext;
    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
            new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
                @Override
                public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
                    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
                }

                @Override
                protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
                    List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
                    // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
                    // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
                    packages.add(new com.ekk.motorcity.MyAppPackage());
                    packages.add(new KeychainPackage()); // --> added package here
                    return packages;
                }
....

I tried adding similarly in my App but getting error as
Native module RNKeychainManager tried to override KeychainModule. Check the getPackages() method in MainApplication.java, it might be that module is being created twice. If this was your intention, set canOverrideExistingModule=true. This error may also be present if the package is present only once in getPackages () but is also automatically added later during build time by autolinking. Try removing the existing entry and rebuild.

Attached screenshot of the error for reference Error - RNKeychainManager
Any suggestions or fixes from the community regarding this issue with react-native-keychain, any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
Tried - automatic linking, options like Keychain.SECURITY_LEVEL and Keychain.STORAGE_TYPE

If you have managed to find a solution to this please post an answer so other people may find it helpful

There is documentation for this.
Xcode Configuration

You need to enable the keychain sharing capability ( Do this for first project )
Enter a name for group of keychain with reverse DNS notation e.g. com.project.test
Go to the second project and enable capability for keychain sharing
Select the same keychain group as first project

note
: You  need to have same developer certificate on both applications.
React Native Keychain
Use the same service key for both storing and retrieving in both applications.

Thank you for your suggestion, but I am facing issue with Android, iOS is working fine.
Please suggest solution for android
